# Confused about Burgers' Equation with an inhomogeneous RHS

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving a question and would appreciate some help. The question is:

> Solve the PDE:
>   $$u_t+u\cdot u_x=1, \>\>\>u(x,0)=x$$
>   for $t\geq0$.

Now I know that the Characteristic Equations are given by:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} &= u(t)\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} &= 1
\end{align*}
I also made auxiliary conditions:
\begin{align*}
x(0) &= x_0\\
z(0) &= z_0 = g(x_0)
\end{align*}
Thus integrating and using auxiliary conditions, I solved that:
$$z(t)=t+z_0, \>\> x(t) = g(x_0)\cdot t+\frac{t^2}{2}+x_0$$
From there I solved for $g(x_0)$:
$$g(x_0) = \frac{x(t)}{t}-\frac{x_0}{t}-\frac{t}{2}$$
By the auxiliary condition $u(x,0)=x$, $g(x_0)=x_0$, and with this in mind I solved for $x_0$:
$$x_0 = \frac{x}{t+1}-\frac{t^2}{2(t+1)}$$
So I deduced that $$u(x,t) = \frac{2x-t^2}{2(t+1)}$$
Did I go about this correctly? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the characteristic curves correctly: they are the parabolas 
$$
x = x_0+x_0t + \frac{t^2}{2}
$$
So, the characteristic through $(x,t)$ originates at $x_0 =  \dfrac{2x-t^2}{2(t+1)}$, as you also found. The mistake is in concluding that $u(x,t) = x_0$. This would be true for homogeneous PDE. But the nonhomogeneity means that $u$ (represented by $z$ in the characteristic equation) changes along the characteristic. Specifically, $z=x_0+t$. So the final answer is
$$
u(x,t) = x_0 + t = \dfrac{2x-t^2}{2(t+1)} + t = \dfrac{2x+t+t^2}{2(t+1)}
$$